# Basic DFS space usage

Tags: python, performance, memory

I have a basic question related to space usage, and I'm using DFS as an example. I'm not sure if the space usage in these few implementations are the same, or if a few actually differ. My interpretation of space usage is directly correlated to what the function allocates. **Can anyone help me verify the space usage of these few examples I made? This is a question on space complexity, and not time + functionality**

Example 1: We allocate a dictionary that will store N nodes. I'm positive this one allocates O(N) space.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, children):
        self.children = children

    def getChildren(self):
        return self.children

def dfs(start):
    stack = []
    visited = {}
    stack.append(start)
    while(len(stack) > 0):
        node = stack.pop()
        if(node not in visited):
            visited[node] = True
            for child in node.getChildren():
                stack.append(child)
```

Example 2: We don't allocate anything in the dfs function, but instead we are given a flag to set on the Node. We aren't allocating anything in the dfs function so it is O(1) space usage.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, children):
        self.children = children
        self.visited = False

    def getChildren(self):
        return self.children

    def getVisited(self):
        return self.visited

    def setVisited(self, visit):
        self.visited = visit

def dfs(start):
        stack = []
        stack.append(start)
        while(len(stack) > 0):
            node = stack.pop()
            if(!node.getVisited()):
                node.setVisited(True)
                for child in node.getChildren():
                    stack.append(child)
```

Example 3: We have an object Node that can be manipulated, but does not have a flag attribute up front. DFS is manually creating a flag on each Node, and thus allocating O(N) space.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, children):
        self.children = children

    def getChildren(self):
        return self.children

def dfs(start):
    stack = []
    stack.append(start)
    while(len(stack) > 0):
        node = stack.pop()
        if(node.visited is not None):
            node.visited = True
            for child in node.getChildren():
                stack.append(child)
```

Comment: Okay, that's not the point of the question. Thank you for at least pointing that out...

Comment: I see, but there are numerous syntax errors in the code you provided, which makes me think this is not the actual code you're using...

Comment: There is no actual code. This is a space usage question.

Comment: ... you **should** change `stack.insert(0, x)` with `stack.append(x)` and `stack.pop(0)` to `stack.pop()`. This wont change what your code does but **will** change the complexity of inserting/popping  from the stack from O(N^2) to O(N).

Comment: @Bakuriu Thank you I will change that, but once again that is not the point of the question. I will clarify that in the question.

Comment: @Taztingo By the way: instead of using a dictionary where all the values are `True` you should instead just use a `set`. Replace `visited[node] = True` with `visited.add(node)` and to see if a node was visited use `if node in visited`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Space complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSPACE) is not determined by *where* the space gets allocated but by *how much* space (memory) is required to hold a given data structure in relation to the number of objects to be processed by an algorithm.

In your examples all data structures require O(N) space (N = # of nodes)

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I forgot about the stack appending for each Node. I know it can be simplified to O(N), but what would the exact complexity be? Would the first one be the only one that is O(2N)? It has to store nodes in the dictionary, and the stack.

Comment: @Taztingo It depends on how you measure space complexity exactly. For example python dictionaries are hashmaps, and typically hashmap have to use more space that the space actually occupied by their elements in order to make the lookup efficient, so storing the elements in both a stack and a dict will consume more than `2N` memory.

Comment: By convention, Big O notation describes an upper bound - the worst case - to the _growth rate_ of a function as opposed to an absolute value. We also say that a function is O(x) "up to constant factors" or `|f(x)| <= c|g(x)|, c > 0` . In other words we assume `N >> c` and hence O(2N) is the same as O(N), that is the growth rate, as N goes to "a sufficiently large number", is determined by N much more than it is by 2.

Comment: Note, it is entirely possible that two implementations use very different amounts of memory yet their growth rates are still O(N). While in theory it doesn't matter in practice it might very well.... To explain that succintly you could say that your examples all use space complexity O(N) _up to constant factors_, but by looking closer you find that example 2 is the most efficient as it has constant factor c = 1 while the others have at least constant factor 2 and thus use much more space.